# PHP: Getting files from ftp server (proftpd)

Tags: php, ftp

I have website, wich loads config files (5-15 per 1 webpage) from remote ftp servers (linux proftpd).

When user opens (refresh) only one web-page - everything is fine, page renders to fast (~100 milliseconds). When user open 4-6 tabs one by one (~1 sec delay between opening tabs) on web browser, avg 1-3 web-pages renders to fast, but 4-6 pages it too sloooow (up to 60 seconds or more).

I find bottleneck: this is ftp_get() php function, that freeze to time of timeout set in ftp_connect() when getting files from ftp. Only ftp_get() freeze web-page rendering.

```
public function getConfigViaFtp($config_name)
{
    $handle = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    ftp_fget($this->getFtpConnectionStream(), $handle, $config_name, FTP_ASCII);
    rewind($handle);

    return stream_get_contents($handle);
}
```

I am ssh to remote ftp server and run ftptop to look on the connections when page freeze. proftpd have only one connection with COMMAND 'RETR'.

ftp_get always succesfuly get first (sometimes up to 5 files) file from ftp, but another files always empty (but exists and not empty on the ftp server) and ftp_get timeouts on this files.

I try to:

```
ob_start(); 
$result = ftp_get($this->getFtpConnectionStream(), 'php://output', $config_name, FTP_ASCII);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

try `ftp_pasv()`

but nothing :( `ftp_get()` and web-page still freeze a lot of time and doesn't load contents of files in end of each web-page.

Whats wrong? proftpd settings (default) or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** ftp_pasv() right after ftp_login(), but NOT after ftp_connect and everithing works fine :)